# XSS - No escaping, but not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, xss, exploit

I have a site where a page `http://www.example.com/errorpage.html?errmsg="Some error string"`

This error string is then rendered into the webpage in a `<p class="error">Some error string</p>` fashion server side, then the HTML is sent to the client.

I've been trying for the past while to see if I can escape this and change the markup without success.

Is it even possible, or is the page secure.

Thanks
-Mitchell

Comment: Tried adding `errmsg=<script>alert(1)</script>`?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Phil: That doesn't work

Comment: @Mitchell Define *"doesn't work"*. Does it produce an alert? Do you see the `<script>` tag as HTML output? What are you doing to circumvent an XSS attack vector. Please show some code

Comment: It renders that as text in the webpage

Comment: Can you link to the page?

Comment: @Mitchell Sounds like you're doing the right thing then but without seeing some code, there could be other vulnerabilities

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to release code, or link to the page(the product is unfinished)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice though.  I'll bring it up in the next meeting just to be safe

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html) has a pretty comprehensive list of CSS/XSS exploits, along with specific examples.   Allowing an error message to be rendered through a query parameter is pretty suspect though, and even if none of these vectors work, that's no guarantee that some vector won't arise in the future.

Comment: My go-to list is https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet